# Setting the axes tick values of a seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to make the x and y axes (including axes tick values) of my jointplot to start and end with specific values and to be scaled in set increments.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = sns.jointplot(x="LONGITUDE", y="LATITUDE", data=data,
                      kind='reg', color="#774499", dropna=True, size=7, space=0.3, ratio=5,
                      xlim=(-180,180), ylim=(-90,90), fit_reg=False);
plt.rc("legend", fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Latitude', fontsize=15)
plt.title('Spatial Location Plot', fontsize=15 )
plt.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=15)
```

[image: This is what I get]

Notice that the lower and upper edges of both axes do not have any tick values. I want the tick values to start and end at the axes edges using exactly the values I specified in xlim() and ylim().

My preferred increments are 90 and 45 degrees for the X and Y axes respectively. So, I want the X axis to look this: -180, -90, 0, 90, 180.
And the Y axis to be: -90, -45, 0, 45, 90. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.ticker`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) to set the `major_locator` on the axes. The `JointGrid` returned by `jointplot` (`g`) has a `ax_joint` attribute, which we can use to set the ticks. To set ticks every multiple of a number, we can use a `MultipleLocator`:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
g.ax_joint.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(90))
g.ax_joint.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(45))
```